# MSBuild CL Task Parameters

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild

I'm trying to automate compiling various open source projects using MSBuild.

I want to add a custom CL.exe flag to my compilation pipeline: set the calling convention to fastcall (in cl.exe this is passed as /Gr).
This means the default cdecl option (/Gd) needs to be overwritten.

I tried setting an MSBuild property but this did not work:

> MSBuild.exe /p:PlatformToolset=v141 /p:Platform=x64 /p:Configuration=Release /p:CallingConvention=/Gr

I also want to do this with a couple of other flags so this isn't isolated to calling convention. I also wish to do this without editing any configuration files, only do it using the CLI.

How can I do this with MSBuild?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried setting an MSBuild property but this did not work. How can I
>   do this with MSBuild?

See msbuild [Global Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#global-properties), the command line only receive msbuild properties while `CallingConvention` is not msbuild property.

I created one C++ project and changed `/Gd to /Gr` in `C/C++=>Advanced` in Debug|X86 configuration and then I see something like this:

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      ...
      <CallingConvention>FastCall</CallingConvention>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      ...
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

It's obvious that `CallingConvention` is just one `Metadata` of `Item` `CLCompile`. It's not msbuild property. So we can't set it in msbuild command-line like this: `msbuild /p:xxx`.

**Possible workaround**:

Since the only difference between using `/Gr` and `/Gd` is the that metadata line:

[image]

So I think we can make one copy of that `ItemDefinitionGroup` in project file and set their conditions like:

```
  <!--ItemDefinitionGroup when using default /Gd-->
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32' AND '$(UseFastCall)' == ''">
    <ClCompile>
     ...
    </ClCompile>
     ...
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <!--ItemDefinitionGroup when using /Gr-->
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32' AND '$(UseFastCall)' != ''">
    <ClCompile>
      ...
      <CallingConvention>FastCall</CallingConvention> <!--The only difference here.-->
    </ClCompile>
      ...
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Then if we pass value to custom property `UseFastCall` like: `MSBuild.exe /p:PlatformToolset=v141 /p:Platform=x86 /p:Configuration=Debug /p:UseFastCall=true`. It should use the `/Gr` metadata. And if we don't pass value to that property, it will use defaut `/Gd`. So workaround is to create custom property to control that behavior. (It's only for Debug|win32, you may need to edit also for other configurations.)

Comment: I am going to parameterize every ClCompile row instead of dividing it into multiple ItemDefinitionGroups, I hoped there was a way to pass compilation flags through MSBuild without touching vcproj.

Thanks!

Comment: @Paul Sorry but that's not supported for now! Msbuild.exe is a core build tool to build most projects in VS IDE. During build it calls cl.exe for C++ projects, csc.exe for C# projects, vbc.exe for VB.net projects., but msbuild.exe doesn't equal to cl.exe. So not every compilation flags can be recognized by msbuild.exe, in this case the `CallingConvention` is something msbuild can't recognize in command-line. So I think if you don't like to touch the vcxproj, then it's just not supported. See my answer you'll know msbuild only receive **msbuild properties** in command-line. It's by design :-)

Comment: Without editing the vcxproj, what you want is not supported yet. It may need some changes to the source code of msbuild.exe... Hope my comment helps to resolve your puzzle.